# Can SQL Query which is provided the same parameters return different data when run through java vs mySQL database?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, prepared-statement, resultset

I have two queries: (one is computing sum of records while the other is selecting all the records)

```
Query 1: 
select sum(tb_nominal) from tb_sec_tran where tb_account_id = 112 and tb_security_id = 234 
and trunc(tb_execution_time) < trunc(to_date('31-12-2017','dd-mm-yyyy');


Query 2: select tb_nominal from tb_sec_tran where tb_account_id = 112 and tb_security_id = 
234 and trunc(tb_execution_time) < trunc(to_date('31-12-2017','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

**What lies in database.**

```
tb_nominal | tb_execution_time
520        | 08-MAR-17
486        | 04-JAN-18
520        | 01-JAN-18
-520       | 31-DEC-17
```

**Case 1:** I ran these two queries on the database(sql developer). For the first query, I am getting 520.0 as the output. For the second query, I am getting 1 record in output with tb_nominal=520.0.

**Case 2:** on java platform, I have implemented the below code:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Double sum = null;
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer(" select sum(tb_nominal) from tb_sec_tran where 
tb_account_id = ? and tb_security_id = ? and trunc(tb_execution_time) < trunc(?) ");

pstmt = m_Connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
pstmt.setLong(1, spekuVO.getContent().getAccountId());
pstmt.setLong(2, spekuVO.getContent().getInstrumentId());
pstmt.setDate(3, toDate.getSQLDatum());
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
   sum = rs.getDouble(1);
 }
```

**Problem:** So when I run the code, instead of 520.0 nominal value, I am getting the sum as 0.0 which is different from the what was returned on the database. Similarly if I make a change in the sql variable by deleting the sum word to make it similar to the query 2, I get two records as in the image which i have attached.

I am completely baffled by the strange behavior. Is there any change made in the processing of JAVA 8 compared to JAVA 6 related to this?
Kindly suggest me if any reason exist for this behavior.

Comment: Unless the query itself is indeterministic or the driver is buggy, the same results will be returned no matter where you query from. It would be a pretty bad design choice to have wrong results returned. Don't blame Java, the fault is in **your** code. Your queries are not the same. You're not calling `to_date` in your Java query.

Comment: Why are creating a `StringBuffer` just to assign it to a `sql` on the next line as a `.toString()`. Why not just assign the constant value to `sql`?

Comment: @Kayaman, Thats what I was thinking. But even if i run the query without to_date,only 1 record is output for the second query in sql developer.
Also, the expression, pstmt.setDate(3, toDate.getSQLDatum()) will serve me just like to_date.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts, I have removed sql.append() statements for this question. So, Stringbuffer in the real code prevents the creation of new String object when ever a change is made in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Java doesn't magically give out wrong results.

Your Java query doesn't contain the `to_date` part that you're using in your other query. Two different queries, two different results.

Comment: Does not the pstmt.setDate(3,toDate.getSQLDatum()) convert the parameter to date type?

Comment: Which database are you using? You've tagged mysql, but it doesn't seem to have `to_date`, but `str_to_date` function.

Comment: I am sorry!!!
I am using oracle and not the mysql.
I really apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Check the results in your program by manually putting all the parameters in the query, then replacing each one with the placeholder to see where it goes wrong.